# Get history of executed queries in VS 2010?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005, visual-studio-2010

I have some problem with finding bug in .net 2.0 application based on the datasets and I don't know why I get wrong data from database.

Is there any way to get history of las executed queries  from visual studio 2010 (debugging program).

I tried this in sql server 2005:

```
SELECT deqs.last_execution_time AS [Time], dest.TEXT AS [Query]
FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats AS deqs
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(deqs.sql_handle) AS dest
ORDER BY deqs.last_execution_time DESC
```

but it gives me only queries I executed in sql server management studio.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [SQL Server Profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187929%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx) to see which queries are executed. Note that this will log all activity on the server, not just the debugged application so you will need to play around with the filters.

Comment: I'd like to add for OP (this answer is how to do it) that unless you profile or log in the client, then nothing will be logged by default.